# file.remove() with dynamic input in R

Tags: r, r-markdown

I create dynamic LaTex reports in R markdown and want to delete the .tex file after the .pdf has been created as part of the overall function `get_report`. The name of the .pdf file in dynamic. I tried

```
file.remove(paste0("/sang/pect/apps/office/admin/", DATA$report_filename, ".tex"))
```

where `DATA$report_filename` is the name of the .pdf that is being created. So if i want to remove the file of a report called "hello", the path would be `/sang/pect/apps/office/admin/hello.tex`

When I call the function mentioned above, I however get an error: 'No such file or directory'

The reason is that R tries to remove the file `/sang/pect/apps/office/admin/.tex`
It just leaves out the dynamic part

But when i run

```
file.remove(paste0("/sang/pect/apps/office/admin/", DATA$report_filename, ".tex"))
```

in the console, all works well.

So what is my mistake?

Comment: Unless you set the `keeptex` option to `true` in the YAML header, the `tex` file is automatically deleted. That does not explain the error you get. Looks like `DATA$report_filename` is `NULL`. You should show some code which yields this problem.

Comment: hmm i did not do anything in the YAML. get_report only has 2 lines: in the first line it renders the rmarkdown document and the second is the one i posted

Comment: Could you show this function `get_report` and a minimal version of the `Rmd` file? This would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If `paste0("/sang/pect/apps/office/admin/", DATA$report_filename, ".tex")` returns "/sang/pect/apps/office/admin/.tex", I would inspect the `DATA$report_filename` vector by e.g. using `print()` function.